# ssl files: Nginx works but Nodejs https module does not?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl, ssl-certificate, node.js

I have a Node instance running on an EC2 instance. I just got my ssl certificate, private key and ca-bundle. so I put them in Nodejs like:

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("/path/to/private/key"),
  crt: fs.readFileSync("/path/to/crt"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync("/path/to/ca")
}

var server = require("https").createServer(options, app).listen(443)
```

But this method never worked. The browser keeps saying **ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH**. I thought this should be the right way to initiate a https server.

After a few hours of not finding any clue, I turned to Nginx. I ran Nginx and set its config to accept ssl through key and crt files. Surprisingly, Nginx handled it well and successfully passed traffic to my Node server (which is now listening on port 3000 as a proxy port). The browsers are also getting content through 443 just fine with a https secure icon lit up.

So the key files are absolutely fine, because Nginx used these files to make things right. So how could Node server not enable ssl? Does it have anything to do with EC2 or AWS in general?

Comment: Please use SSLlabs.com analyzer for your 443 port if it behaves bad. It's a more verbose report.

Comment: I doubt this is anything to do with EC2 / AWS. I don't know node well enough to give you an answer though.

Comment: What version of node.js is it? And why are you doing this at all?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Im using v10.0.0 for node. I dont have another instance in public subnet to have aws load balance it for me, so I cant have my ssl certificates installed there. Instead I went for installing Nginx as a reverse proxy myself. It worked out fine. Nginx allows full https connection for my website but Node https module seems to be failing.

Comment: @kubanczyk ssl checkers simply say can't get ssl certificates. I guess there is something wrong with node TLS module. Nginx is completely fine with the certificates I currently hold.

Comment: [The key in options for a cert(s)-in-PEM file is `cert` not `crt`.](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks alot! saved my day. It was very stupid of me lol !!